# ofstream not working on linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++-4.7

i have a simple test code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
std::ofstream strm = std::ofstream("test.txt");
strm << "TEST123";
strm.close();
return 0;
}
```

if i compile this on windows it works perfectly. however when i compile it on debian with the following command:
g++-4.7 -std=c++0x -lpthread TestStream.cpp -ldl -o TestStream
than it gives the following output:
[image]

i have googled this error to no avail. does anybody know how to fix this? i use a lot of ofstreams in my projects and would like to compile it on linux also.

EDIT: so i have it compiling now thanks to WinterMute however now it prints empty files. how do i fix this?

EDIT2: dunno why but second time compiling it worked. thx!

Comment: Re: edit: Do you have write permissions to the working directory/the target file?

Comment: You know, there's not really any reason for posting a picture instead of raw text...

Comment: @Deduplicator there is if the text is not easily copied

Comment: @Wintermute yes i have.

Comment: So, your console is deficient in copy-paste-ability, but making a screenshot works? Curious setup, didn't think there is such on Linux...

Comment: @Deduplicator its called windows and putty lol.

Comment: You can copy and paste from and to putty with the mouse. See http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter3.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
std::ofstream strm("test.txt");
```

This:

```
std::ofstream strm = std::ofstream("test.txt");
```

requires a copy constructor that `std::ofstream` doesn't have or a move constructor that is available only since C++11. GCC 4.7 does not have full support for C++11 yet, and apparently this is one of the missing features.

In the comments, T.C. mentions that moveable streams won't come to gcc until version 5, which is planned to be released this year. This took me by surprise because gcc claimed full C++11 support with version 4.8.1 -- which is true for the compiler, but not for libstdc++. Reality bites.

So it is perhaps worth mentioning that [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) (a c++ standard library implementation affiliated with clang and llvm) implements moveable streams, and both clang 3.5 and gcc 4.9 (those are the ones I have here and tried) compile the original code if it is used instead of libstdc++.

Comment: why is this not necessary on windows?

Comment: Because Microsoft would like you to write code that only compiles and works on Windows.

Comment: ok so now it compiles but it doesnt print anything to the file. is this another linux problem?

Comment: It's no extension. Streams are movable in C++11.

Comment: I do love how people like to bash Microsoft even when it's GCC/libstdc++ that's being noncompliant here. `std::ofstream strm = std::ofstream("test.txt");` requires an accessible copy **or move** constructor. `std::ofstream` is movable, and the code should compile. libstdc++ didn't implement movable streams.

Comment: This is not a linux "problem".

Comment: Oh, that's right. I'll fix it in a minute; just let me look up when gcc implemented it so I can mention that.

Comment: Movable streams won't be here until GCC 5.

Comment: Huh, the gcc website lied to me. Back to the edit tool, I guess.

Comment: @Wintermute, what the website refers to full support for C++11 _language_ features, not a complete standard library implementation. The library in the GCC trunk is complete except for the unicode `codecvt` facets and `wstring_convert` and `wbuffer_convert`, but the status for 4.8 is shown at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: So it appears. I just tried it with libc++, and gcc compiles it happily. I kind of assumed that gcc's advertised compliance included libstdc++, and I was sadly mistaken.

Comment: The C++11 status page doesn't cover any library features, and https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html says "The status of the library implementation can be tracked in this [table](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)"

Comment: I was looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html (and the 4.8 version of that page). I should have looked more closely; mea culpa.

Comment: Since no one else has said it: move semantics for streams is all nice and dandy, and there are places where it is useful (e.g. a vector of streams), but in this case, there's really no reason not to use `std::ofstream strm("test.txt");`.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but the suggested change: std::ofstream strm = std::ofstream("test.txt"); does not work for me. Is there another API that I can use for writing to a file in linux?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ofstream strm = std::ofstream("test.txt");
```

`ofstream` doesn't have copy constructor.